# Creating node inside a method

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to "convert" this code to a method that will create node items. I know that I have to use a for loop but I cant figure out a way to get this done.

Original Code:

```
public class GenericLinkedListDemo
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 LinkedList3<Entry> list = new LinkedList3<Entry>( );
 Entry entry1 = new Entry(1);
 list.addToStart(entry1);
 Entry entry2 = new Entry(2);
 list.addToStart(entry2);
 Entry entry3 = new Entry(3);
 list.addToStart(entry3);
```

}

What I did until now was create a method in the GenericLinkedListDemo that sends the parameter:

```
public class GenericLinkedListDemo
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     LinkedList3<Entry> list = new LinkedList3<Entry>( );
    addToList(list, 7);
```

to my method:

```
public static void addToList(LinkMaster<Entry> L, int n){
        for (int i = n; i>0; i--) { 
            //This is where I want to put my "converted code"
        }
    }
```

I already did all the methods to create the node(LinkMaster). I just want to know how to make this piece of code above works in the way that I just need to send a parameter to the code.

Comment: What is `addToList` supposed to do? What are you expecting to be added to the list by this method?

Comment: In the original code I need to enter with entry for each node that I want to create(entry1, entry2,entry3). What I want is a for loop that will make the same process (create nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this

```
public static void addToList(LinkMaster<Entry> list, int n){//here n will determine number of entry node to be added
        for (int i = n; i>0; i--) { 
            Entry entry = new Entry(i);
            list.addToStart(entry);
        }
    }
```

If you pass n = 7 ,then 7 entry node will be added to the list.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. I did the changes and eclipse gives me the following message: list cannot be resolved and The local variable list may be not initialized. I have been trying this the whole night.